Switch 12V from plug transformer with 2N5401 PNP and 3.3V logic
I've got a breadboard with a typical breadboard power supply that provides 3.3V to the power rail on the breadboard.
I currently have three types of transistors at my disposal: 2N2222 (NPN), 2N5401 (PNP), 2N5551 (PNP). The relay is one that you click onto a DIN rail, and the coil is 12V, draws around 60mA (measured), and has a built-in flyback diode and LED (and resistor for its LED).
My 12V power comes from a wall outlet adaptor plug.
My goal is to switch the relay with 3.3V logic, and that 3.3V signal will come from an ESP32 (but not yet). I prefer high side switching the 12V because that feels more logical.
My first tries were high side switching the 12V with a 2N2222. This wasn't a success because I read high side switching with an NPN transistor is hard. It only lit up the LED on the relay very blurry. Relay didn't switch.
When I used it for low side switching it worked, but something seemed wrong because the LED on the breadboard power supply started to shine brighter than normal.
Of course I connected the 3.3V ground with the negative part of the twin wire coming from the 12V adaptor, otherwise the transistor does nothing of course. But it feels like there's an unwanted destructive current path going somewhere and I don't quite understand what's going on or if this is normal.
Since I read high side switching with an NPN is not desirable in most cases, I used the PNP 2N5401. Now I've got the following circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But the relay doesn't do anything. If I substitute the 12V part by a 5V circuit with an LED and 220 Ω resistor the LED shines very weakly. When I connect the base of the 2N5401 to ground explicitly, the LED shines very bright.
Can someone help me with this simple circuit? I think the problem has to do with the connection between ground of 3.3V circuit and negative of 12V adaptor. Everytime I think there's current leaking somewhere and I risk destroying components.
I studied "higher professional education" electrical engineering, but in the Netherlands so we didn't really learn anything.

I now realize the base of my 2N5401 is a floating pin if not connected to ground some way like through a resistor of big enough resistance.

"I prefer high side switching the 12V because that feels more logical"
It's more complex and you should only resort to fabricating a high-side switch (two transistors in this case) if there's a good reason.
The easiest way is to use a low side switch with an NPN BJT or N-channel MOSFET. Since you have only a 3.3V signal available the latter would have to be a logic-level part.
Since your relay draws 60mA you can use a common BJT such as 2N4401. Base current should be around 1/10 to 1/20 of that current or about 3-6mA.
With 3.3V representing 'on' you'd need a base resistor of about 560Ω- the circuit would look like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

A high-side switch solution would look more like this:

simulate this circuit
Frankly, it sounds like you may have damaged parts mixed in with good ones and you should use brand-new parts wired carefully or find some way to verify the condition of what you have or it might get very frustrating. Check that your relay actually has the flyback diode as you say (and if it does, getting the polarity backward will likely destroy the transistor and/or the diode.

I would have thought a NPN used as a low-side switch would be simpler such as:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Notes:

Haven't shown a flyback diode as the question says the relay contains a built in one.
The 2N2222 has a current gain of ~100, so the 1 K base resistor should allow the 2N2222 to saturate with 60 mA from the relay coil. The base resistor could be increased if you to reduce the current from the ESP32 GPIO output.


Here are a couple of high-side "switches" using NPN (left) and PNP (right):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The left-hand NPN is configured "common-collector", also know as "emitter-follower". If input potential \$V_{IN}\$ at node IN is swept from 0V to 12V, and we measure the potential \$V_X\$ at its "output" node X, this is what we get:

This is a very analogue response:
$$ V_Y = V_{IN} - 0.7V $$
Notice that there is no signal inversion; output changes in the same direction as input.
Given that your inputs will be either 0V or +3.3V, according to that graph, at those input levels output X is only 0V or +2.6V. Clearly that's not nearly enough to power your relay coil. An emitter-follower does what the name suggests. Emitter X follows the base in potential, but about 0.7V lower, and this analogue behaviour isn't often compatible with something that should be either on or off.
The second right-hand circuit has a PNP transistor configured with "common-emitter", and its behaviour is very, very different. The same sweep of the input gives us this response at Y:

This response is more "digital", on or off, being mostly 0V or +12V, ideal for operating the relay coil. It also inverts, meaning output potential \$V_Y\$ changes in the opposite direction to input \$V_{IN}\$.
The most important thing to note is that to switch this "off", \$V_Y = 0V\$, input potential must exceed \$12V-V_{BE} = 12V-0.7V = 11.3V\$. Your inputs of 0V and +3.3V are never that high, and can never switch the transistor (and relay coil) off.
Your preference for high side switching because "that feels more logical" has tripped you up. It has its advantages, no doubt, such as being able to ground the load. However, high-side switches are inconvenient when the the power supply of the switched element (12V in your case) is different from the power supply of the digital circuitry producing the control signal (3.3V).
In such cases, level translation is required, and you can refer to Spehro's answer for an example of using a second transistor to achieve that.

A low-side "switch" using a PNP transistor would require it to be connected common-collector, which would therefore also be an analogue "emitter follower", unsuitable for use with a 0V or +3.3V control signal. A single transistor solution in a low-side switching scenario, then, must necessarily be common-emitter NPN:

simulate this circuit
